# Overload cast operator in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, casting, operator-overloading

Is it possible to overload the cast operator in Kotlin?

Something like:

```
fun MyClass.cast(): String = this.toString()
fun MyClass.cast(): Int = this.hashCode()
fun MyClass.cast(): Map<String, MyClass> = mapOf(this.toString() to this)
```

And then I could use it like

```
val x: String = myClass as String
val y: Int = myClass as Int
val z: Map<String, MyClass> = myClass as Map<String, MyClass>
```

And

```
myClass is String // true
myClass is Int // true
myClass is Map<String, MyClass> // true
myClass is List<String> // false
```

Comment: No, casting on the JVM doesn't create a new object. It changes how the VM sees the same object.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Why do we have to keep repeating this point?  I can't work out why there's so much confusion about it...  But in case it's not clear enough: **In Kotlin, a cast doesn't _convert_ a value to a new type; it promises the compiler that the value is _already_ of that type.**  So you'll get a runtime error if it's not.  To convert, use a conversion method, usually named like `toXXX()`.

Comment: @gidds I got to this question because I want to refactor a codebase with to few tests from passing around a basic list<myType> to passing around a myTypeList that I can give customized behaviour. Yes, there seems to be reasons to not extend the basic list. So, I'd really like to define cast to list to return the member containing the original list. If I have to add toList everywhere it will not be an easy refactoring, and the code will actually be less readable for a long time.

Comment: @SamuelÅslund Does that customised behaviour involve changing the behaviour of existing method? If not, then you might get what you need by adding an extension method on `List<MyType>`. — But a cast would be ` as MyList`, which isn't significantly shorter than `.toMyList()`, so I'm not sure what a redefined cast would give you here anyway. (Unless you mean an _implicit_ conversion — in which case look to Scala for the bag of worms that opens up.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible.  You cannot do this with casting; you can only do it with explicit functions that do the conversion.

Comment: Too bad. Some interesting things would be possible with that.